# Sequelize not wait for function value

Tags: javascript, node.js

in my Sequelize where condition I have to call a function that would return an array like [118, 116, 125]. my code is:

```
function getQuestionForQuickPreparation(req, res){

let user_id =  req.params.id;

async function have_to_skip(type){
    
    const already_taken = await db.sequelize.query("SELECT `question_id` FROM `Quick_Preparations` AS `Quick_Preparations` WHERE `Quick_Preparations`.`question_type` = " + type + " AND `Quick_Preparations`.`user_id` = "+ user_id, {
        type: db.sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT
    });

    let questions_id_array = already_taken.map((taken) => taken.question_id)
    
    // console.log(questions_id_array) *1
    return questions_id_array;
    
}

// console.log(have_to_skip(2)) *2

models.Question_Bank_Questions.findAll({
    where: {
        [Sequelize.Op.not]: [
            { id: have_to_skip(2) }
        ]
    },
    order: Sequelize.literal('rand()'), 
    limit: 1
}).then(async(question_bank_questions) =>{

    ----
    
    res.json({
        code:    200,
        question: question_bank_questions
    });
    
});
```

}

inside "have_to_skip" function [marked as *1] I got my data as [118,116,112,245]. and the second console [marked as *2] return me

```
Promise { '<pending>' }
```

message.

Answer (score 0):

When your code is dependent on another function, make sure you always return value from it.

In your case, you're just calling the function but not returning the value.

```
async function have_to_skip(type){
    // Type: 1 = Normal Question, 2 = Question Bank Question, 3 = Current Affairs Questions;
    
    const already_taken = await db.sequelize.query("SELECT `question_id` FROM `Quick_Preparations` AS `Quick_Preparations` WHERE `Quick_Preparations`.`question_type` = " + type + " AND `Quick_Preparations`.`user_id` = "+ user_id, {
        type: db.sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT
    });

    let questions_id_array = already_taken.map((taken) => taken.question_id)
    return questions_id_array; // this is what you need!
}
```

Comment: you need to debug the return value to see if it exists. try replacing return with return [actual_id_from_db] and see if it works. if so, then you just need to pass relevant ID when calling the func

Comment: I update my question. would you please read it again?

Comment: its because the function is asnyc so the initial state of promise is pending. your code should anyway work with return in place.. whats the output other than promise pending when you call func ?